# Page becomes blank on posting paypal button code in tinymce

Tags: php, paypal, tinymce-4

I have a paypal button code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="YYY8W3A9772ZU">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I paste above code in tinymce Tools>Sourcecode:
But

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="YYY8W3A9772ZU">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

puts error while posting values to another php page. The page on which it's being posted becomes blank while any other values are working fine.
 I have checked tinymce configurations but didn't solve.